# Volumetric water content and EC measurement by Teros 12 sensors from Meter

Tags: sensors, soil

We are doing Mid scale experiment in lab with soil. We are using Teros 12 sensors from Meter Group to measure the volumetric water content (VWC) and electrical conductivity (EC) of the soil. I wanted to know if anyone has used this sensors before? The manufacturer says that VWC measurement is independent of EC. However, We are getting some weird results and we doubt that both measurement are corelated. Does any one know have had the same problem?

(https://www.metergroup.com/en/meter-environment/products/teros-12-soil-moisture-sensor)

Comment: So, what calibration testing have you done? That would be my first step.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Solar. We did some calibration, with water and the substrate and we did find that use of substrate with certain EC effects the reading of VWC but we could not exactly get the relationship from our calibration.